# Special characters break pagination links

Tags: cakephp, pagination, special-characters

### Special Characters and Pagination

I'm using cakephp with charset=iso-8859-1. I know, I'd love to be using UTF-8, but this would be a bigger problem.

The thing is, when I have a special character like "ñ" the pagination links break.

If I don't use any special characters, pagination works fine.

The controller

```
        $this->paginate = array(
            'limit' => self::MAX_PRODUCTOS_POR_PAGINA,
            'order' => 'Producto.id DESC',
            'conditions' => array($conditions, 'Producto.visible' => true)
        );
        $this->set('productos', $this->paginate());
```

The View:

```
echo $this->paginator->next(' Siguiente > ', null, ' Siguiente > ', array('class' => 'disabled'));
```

**For the "next page" link**
I should get this link:
*http://mysite.com.ar/Productos/buscar/señuelos/page:2*

Instead, I'm getting:
*http://mysite.com.ar/Productos/buscar/se%F1uelos*

Any Ideas?

Comment: "but this would be a bigger problem" could you elaborate? actually it is usually the other way around. without uft8 you have a huge mess...

Comment: Please read note under the answer.

Comment: that still doesnt explain why you are not completely switching to utf8. why this would be a bigger problem for you.

Comment: Because i have more than 150,000 files encoded with various formats and I tried to bulk change them without success. Also in the "migration" efort I started getting a lot of bad characters so I canceled the plan. I had to change the database encodings, files encodings, configurations, etc, and I think it's not worth the effort.@mark

Comment: I see. "encoded with various formats" sounds not that good, either, though :) But i agree, bulk changing is not an easy task. many things can and will go wrong. Bear in mind for your next "new" project that there is nothing else besides utf8 if you want to stay out of trouble in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ñ is %F1 in html entity so thats not wrong, it's weird that it broke the pagination, before you couldn't put ñáéíóú in urls so urlencode was used you can always use [ulrdecode](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urldecode.php) so it shows ñ

```
echo urldecode($this->paginator->next(' Siguiente > ', null, ' Siguiente > ', array('class' => 'disabled')));
```

The cakephp way of doing it would be to set the escape option to false so it won't put a html entity instead of the ñ like this

```
echo $this->paginator->next(' Siguiente > ', array('escape'=>false), ' Siguiente > ', array('class' => 'disabled'));
```

make sure this doesn't break with any parameter :D

look the api for [more info](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelpernext)

Comment: I'm going to have to be honest... There was a misconfiguration on my core.php file. I should have noticed... The app was configured as UTF-8 in this line:  
    `Configure::write('App.encoding', 'ISO-8859-1');`
The real fix was to change that to ISO-8859-1.